# A question about groups as categories.

Tags: category-theory

I am currently reading about categories. Groups as categories are so described:

Let $G$ be a finite group. Then we can form an object $B_G$, which is nothing but $*$, an arbitrary element. $Hom(B_G,B_G)$ contains all elements $g\in G$ such that $g$ maps $*\to *$. Also, the operation on $Hom(B_G,B_G)$ is nothing but the binary operation on $G$.

I don't understand how $g\in G$ maps $*\to *$. Wouldn't it be more intuitive to have $G$ as the object $B_G$ and all its automorphisms as $Hom(B_G,B_G)$, with composition as the operator defined for automorphisms?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I find the formulation that you quote not particularly clear. Maybe you should approach it from the other direction: Say, you have a category with only one object such that every morphism is an isomorphism. What can you say about this category? You should come to the conclusion, that this is just a group.

Comment: The key is to make the group operation corresponds to composition of morphisms in the category. Each element of $G$ becomes a morphism on $*$. Having one object in a category means all morphisms can be composed. Your idea about automorphisms is not far off though. You can put $G$ as the only object instead of $*$, and put as morphisms permutations on $G$ corresponding to how $G$ acts on itself.

Comment: The real point is that objects of a category do not have to be sets, and morphisms do not have to be maps.

Comment: An arbitrary element of what? Of $G$?

Comment: @ZhenLin- That doesn't answer my specific question, although it is indeed illuminating. What does $*\to *$ even mean, if it is not a mapping from $*$ to itself? And how does $g\in G$ map $*$ to itself? Doesn't it somehow have to operate on $*$ to map it to something? Is such an operation even defined, considering $*$ is not an element in $G$?

Comment: @Ayush: $* \to *$ is notation for an (unnamed) arrow of the category whose source and target are $*$. One description of categories that you might find illuminating is that a category is a graph (more precisely, a directed multigraph with loops), along with a partially defined multiplication operation for edges. (and the category axioms must be satisfied, of course)

Answer (score 5):

Well, the observation is that a group $G$ may be identified with an abstract category which has only one object and which the set of endomorphisms of this object coincides with $G$.

You have to keep in mind that a category is abstractly defined as a class of objects endowed with sets of morphisms (for each ordered pair of objects) and a composition satisfying some axioms ( see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory ).

This definition is as abstract as the definition of a group. We don't say anything about the nature of an element of group. Similarly, we don't say anything about the nature of the objects or the nature of the morphisms in a category. We say that a group is a set endowed with a binary operation satisfying some conditions. And, on the other hand, in the definition of a category, for each ordered pair $ (A,B) $ of objects in a given category, we have a set of morphisms $ Hom(A,B) $.

So, you may define abstract categories, as you can define abstract groups (we can define a category defining the composition, the class of objects and the sets of morphisms).

Given a group $G$ , you may construct a category with only one object $ \ast $ such that $ Hom (\ast , \ast ) = G $ and the composition is the product of the group $ G $.
To prove this, you need only to verify whether the axioms of a category are satisfied.... Indeed, you may prove that the category of categories with only one object and which all morphisms are isomorphisms is *equivalent* to the category of groups.

Furthermore, it is possible to construct a "more concrete" category from a group $ G $. Using the Cayley theorem, we may prove that each group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of Bijections(G). So, you may consider the category with only one object $G$ and the morphisms being the maps $ f_g: G\to G $, $f_g(h) = g h $ (for each $g\in G $).

Comment: +1 great and complete answer, but maybe you put too much stuff. Your answer seems a little hard to read, may I suggest you try cut off some additional details reference like the last two paragraphs and left those as comments? I think it would improve the question.

Comment: One more suggestion (hope you don't mind): I would eliminate the *Last remark* label, since that's more *the answer* than a remark :)

Comment: Thank you. I guess you are right, but I am writing from my cell phone. So I will do the suggested edits later.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa I think you meant : "it would improve the *answer* :-)

Comment: Fernando: if by "category of categories with only one object and which all morphisms are isomorphisms" you mean that the categories may have different, yet single, objects, then this category is only equivalent to the category of groups, since you can have isomorphic categories - differing only in their single object - being mapped to the same group .

Comment: At last, it is possible to prove, using Yoneda lemma, that each category with only one object can be embedded in the category $Set$ of sets (and the embedding functor is the reprsentable functor): it would show you that all categories with only one object are somehow concrete. And the morphisms of these kind of categories may be interpreted as being "functions".

Comment: Anyway, as I said, it is important to keep in mind that an abstract category would be defined abstractly: and you may don't know the nature of the morphisms.
And the result I told you about categories with only object is not general: there are categories which cannot be embedded in the category of Sets (and there are many important categories holding this property (as the homotopy category - Freyd proved that it cannot be embedded in the category of sets)).

Comment: @magma you are right, I was really thinking about the skeleton categories - but I made the edit. Thank you!

Comment: @Fernando are you sure about the non existance of the embedding? Consider any category $\mathbf C$ to every object $x \in \mathbf C$ you can associate the set $F(x)=\bigsqcup_{c \in \mathbf C}\mathbf C(c,x)$ and for every $f \colon x \to y$ in $\mathbf C$ you can associate the function $F(f) \colon F(x) \to F(y)$ defined as $F(f)(g) = f \circ g$ for every $g \colon c \to x$. These data should form a functor from $\mathbf C$ which is an embedding.

Comment: Injectivity on objects is garanted by the fact that if $x \ne y \in \mathbf C$ then $1_x \in F(x) \setminus F(y)$ and $1_y \in F(y) \setminus F(x)$. From this follows that morphisms having different sources or targets are sent in different functions by $F$.
So at most parallel morphisms can be identified by $F$, that's not the case since if $f,g \colon x \to y$ and $F(f)=F(g)$ then $f=f\circ 1_X=F(f)(1_x)=F(g)(1_x)=g \circ 1_x=g$. This proves also injectivity on the arrow part, hence $F$ is an embedding.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa Indeed, there is a theorem which says that all *small* category can be embedded in the category of sets. 
Your argument proved it. (But note that you did need the hypothesis of $ C $ being small to define $ F(x) $.) 
But the homotopy category is not small. :) And Freyd proved that it can't be embedded in the category of sets. Take a look at http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/6/tr6abs.html

Comment: Of course, the problem is that when doing category theory I always suppose to work with an infinite hierarchy of universes (Tarski-Grothendieck theory, or a rich enough type theory). Thanks for pointing out the needed correction :)

Comment: @GiorgioMossa $ F(x) $ defined above in your comment is not a set, unless the category is somehow small. So you should add in your hypothesis something to assure that $F(x) $ would be a set.

Comment: @Fernando As I said above I've assumed that I was working in a different foundational theory than ZFC: one in which we have proper classes as set-like object, and classes-of-classes and so on. :)

Comment: Sorry about the last comment. Anyway, I believe the result you showed is very interesting. When I was writing the answer, I thought about writing about this result. But, as you told before, my answer was already to long.
Notice, however, that the result you proved is not as canonical as the result on categories with only one objects (or monoids). Because that result on monoids is such that the "embedding functor" is the representable functor.

Answer (score 4):

A group "is the same thing as a category with one object, such that all morphisms are invertible." By this I mean given a group $G$ there is a category with one object X with Hom(X, X) = G, unique up to isomorphism [not just equivalence!] of categories. Conversely, given a category with one object such that all morphisms are invertible, the (only) hom set in the category is certainly a group.

I've never heard of giving X the same name as the multiplication operation on G. That's an odd convention -- are you sure you are reading it right? I am sure that if it is in a textbook, there must be a cool reason to think of it that way, but I can't think of one. The point is that it doesn't matter what you name the only object in the category.

Comment: $*$ is just an asterisk here, not the operation.

Comment: it seems like OP thinks it is the operation ? But it makes a bunch more sense if you are right. Maybe the book accidentally overloaded the notation $*$ :-) i can see how that would be confusing.

Comment: haha you're quite right $*$ is not the operation on the group. It is just an arbitrary element.

Comment: I've made the relevant edits. Could you elaborate why for a group, the category can contain only one element (or am I reading too deeply into it?)

Comment: Categories do not contain 'elements' but 'objects'. If you have a category with more than one object then arrows $f$ and $g$ will exist such that $f\circ g$ is not defined. Then composition cannot be identified with the multiplication in a group. Two things are needed here: exactly one object and all arrows must be invertible. If the first condition is not met and the second is, then you are not dealing with a group but with a groupoid.